# What's the type of a class inside an object inside a trait

Tags: scala, casting, pattern-matching, akka

This is a problem of pattern matching  inside the Recieve of an akka actor.

I have this code:

```
class ActorReservation(reservation: Reservation) extends Actor {
  import Entry._
  import Customer._

  def receive: Actor.Receive = messages

  def messages: Receive = {
    case Entry.Get.Result(obj) => // process entry

    case Customer.Get.Result(obj) => // process customer
  }

  def test: Receive = {
    case e =>
      println(s"ClassName -> ${e.getClass.getName}")
      println(s"isInstanceOf[GenericMessages#Get] -> ${isInstanceOf[GenericMessages[AppAny]#Get]}")
  }
}

object Entry extends GenericMessages[EntryEntity]
object Customer extends GenericMessages[CustomerEntity]

trait GenericMessages[A <: AppAny] {
  case class Get(id: Int)
  object Get { case class Result(obj: Option[A]) }
} //trait

trait AppAny
case class EntryEntity(id: Int) extends AppAny
case class CustomerEntity(id: Int) extends AppAny
```

My actor could receive two messages: `Entry.Get.Result`, `Customer.Get.Result`, when it receives the first one everything goes find, but when the second arrives it throws and exception that `Customer` can cast to `Entry`, this is because the second messages is been caught by the first `case`.

Then I change the receive with

```
  def receive: Actor.Receive = test
```

both message shows the same class name `GenericMessages$Get$Result`, so thats why both messages falls in the first `case`.

I try to create a generic `case` for both messages with `GenericMessages#Get` but this makes references to the class `Get` inside `GenericMessages` instead of the object `Get`.

So, my question is: Is there a way to reference the `Result` class inside the `Get` object of the `GenericMessages` trait? Is there another way I could make the `case` to avoid this pattern match problem?

---

**Additional information:**
The real actor is an implementation of an generic actor because I would need the same behavior in other actors.

The messages `Entry.Get.Result`, `Customer.Get.Result` are responses of a previous message send by the same actor (`anotherActor ! Customer.Get`) and is implemented in this way because I prefer to parallel calls than linear calls. The linear solution is to have one method to receive the first message than use `become` to change to another receive and process the second message. I want to avoid this linear approach because 1. I prefer it to be a parallel process and 2. it breaks the abstraction I made.

Comment: Isn't that like saying "how'd I distinguish Long's in two different classes?" They're essentially the same, aren't they? There needs to be some external way (not within the Long instance) to work out which class the Long instance belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

I decided to add a third `object` besides `Entry` and `Customer`

```
private object Messages extends GenericMessages[AppAny]
```

and change the receive function with this

```
def messages: Receive = {
  case Messages.Get.Result(obj) => 
    obj match {
      case Some(e: Entry) =>     // process entry
      case Some(c: Customer) =>  // process customer
    }
}
```

now it works as it needs.

---

The full code:

```
class ActorReservation(reservation: Reservation) extends Actor {
  import Entry._
  import Customer._

  def receive: Actor.Receive = messages

  def messages: Receive = {
    case Messages.Get.Result(obj) => 
      obj match {
        case Some(e: Entry) =>     // process entry
        case Some(c: Customer) =>  // process customer
      }
  }
}

private object Messages extends GenericMessages[AppAny]
//I still need this two objects because they are part of 
//other service that use this messages
object Entry extends GenericMessages[EntryEntity]
object Customer extends GenericMessages[CustomerEntity]

trait GenericMessages[A <: AppAny] {
  case class Get(id: Int)
  object Get { case class Result(obj: Option[A]) }
} //trait

trait AppAny
case class EntryEntity(id: Int) extends AppAny
case class CustomerEntity(id: Int) extends AppAny
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution (which is very ugly): Make entry and customer into classes:

```
case class Entry() extends GenericMessages[EntryEntity]
case class Customer() extends GenericMessages[CustomerEntity]
```

then create an entry and customer instance:

```
val entry = Entry()
val customer = Customer()
```

and pass them as parameters to your ActorReservation actor (and anybidy who needs it). Then create and match like this:

```
entry.Get.Result
customer.Get.Result
```

**But this is bad design.**

I suggest avoiding generics when working with actors. Type erasure becomes a problem when you need to match types at runtime.
If I were you, I would redo the design.